# read images from root directory in subdomain with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain like example.com where root directory is web.
I have created a subdomain happy.example.com where directory is outside web folder called happy and connected it to happy.example.com.

My webpage tree looks like

```
happy
web/images
```

So all my images for root directory are stored in (web/images)

```
example.com/images
```

So a full path to an image can be

```
example.com/images/me.png
```

Now i have created a sudbdomain which i call:

```
happy.example.com
```

What i would like to do is if i type

```
happy.example.com/images/me.png
```

then i should be able to see the picture. 
So somehow i need to link all images folder to a subdomain from root directory in web. 
I hope you guys got my question.
I guess i shoud have an htaccess file with all funny stuff in happy folder?

Cheerz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the two document roots of your two domains aren't connect to each other (one inside the other, or the same), you'll need to either redirect or proxy, or, use a script.

To redirect is easiest, but it'll change the URL in the browser's location bar:

```
Redirect 301 /images http://example.com/images
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://example.com/images/$1 [L,R=301]
```

To proxy, you need to have mod_proxy loaded, which isn't always the case if you're using a webhost or hosting service. But you can use the `P` flag in mod_rewrite to do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://example.com/images/$1 [L,P]
```

The last option is to route all image request to a script, like a php script or something. And the script itself returns the image:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /load_image.php?image=$1 [L]
```

then you'd have something like:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    readfile('../web/images/' . $_GET['image']);
?>
```

Obviously, you'd need to check the extension and return the correct content type depending on the image type.

Comment: I could just give u the biggest hug ever :)
Option with mod_rewrite worked for me...